# React Js component rendering only once after state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm quite new to ReactJS and my problems is quite unusual, may be occurring simply because I don't implement things the way they are meant to be.

So basically speaking, this was working fine before, but I needed to add some new features, and... well, something's off.

To start with - `ConvFrame` is top component, appearing at the top on the page and it consists of `ConvForm` component (to add new queries) and `ConvList` where unassigned and new calls go. The `ConvList` here has ID and Key of 1.

There is also list of workers below, they are using `ConvForm` only, the fields themselves are dropzones, which allow to assign new call tasks quickly. The `ConvList` here have Id and Key equal to id of worker.

As the `ConvList` is rendered it queries server for jobs within the list. And this works just fine for all of them. However, there seems to be some weird problem when new item is added via `ConvForm`. It calls `handleCommentSubmit()` function, calls `this.loadCommentsFromServer();` (stupid, I know!) and then sets new state for records `this.setState({records: data});`

When first record is added the `/api/zlecenia` is called twice. Once from the `loadCommentsFromServer()` inside `ConvFrame` and second time from within `ConvList`. Adding second record via form calls it once, the component seem to not react to the state change. Something is badly implemented , I guess.

Here's the source code:
Conversations.js

```
//For dragging
var placeholder = document.createElement("div");
placeholder.className = "placeholder";
var dragged;
var over;

/**
 * Conversation
 * Should be used for listing conversation blocks, adds class based on age of task.
 * Detects drag events, renders block, calls dragEnd function to append block to new
 * location and uses props.OnDrop function to pass id of element and target id of worker
 */
window.Conversation = React.createClass({
    dynamicClass: function () {
        return "convo " + this.props.delay;
    },
    dragStart: function (e) {
        dragged = e.currentTarget;
        over = null;
        e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
        e.dataTransfer.setData("text/html", e.currentTarget);
    },
    dragEnd: function (e) {
        $(dragged).show();
        $(placeholder).remove();
            console.log(over, over.className);
        if (over && over.className === "candrop") {
            var id = Number(dragged.dataset.id);

            this.props.onDrop({id: id, target: over.id});
            over.appendChild(dragged);
        }else{
            console.log('returning base:' + over);
           $(dragged).parent().append(dragged);
        }
    },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div draggable="true" data-id={this.props.id} onDragEnd={this.dragEnd} onDragStart={this.dragStart} className={this.dynamicClass()}  >
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
});

/**
 * ConvList
 * Displays conversation dropdown list. I should aim to make it single component, do not repeat for workers.
 * Detects dragOver for .candrop and place some funny placeholder. Detect position change from Conversation view
 * call master class from parent component and pass data. Detect delete event.
 */
window.ConvList = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {data: []};
    },
    loadConvsFromServer: function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: baseUrl + '/api/zlecenia',
            type: 'GET',
            data: {id: this.props.id},
            success: function (data) {
                this.setState({data: data});
            }.bind(this),
            error: function (xhr, status, err) {
                console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
            }.bind(this)
        });
    },
    componentDidMount: function () {
        this.loadConvsFromServer();
    },
    dragOver: function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(dragged).fadeOut();
        if (e.target.className === "candrop") {
            if (e.target.className == "placeholder")
                return;
            over = e.target;
            e.target.appendChild(placeholder, e.target);
        }
    },
    updatePosition: function (data) {
        console.log('update convo %d for member %e', data.id, data.target);

        $.ajax({
            url: baseUrl + '/api/zlecenia',
            type: 'PUT',
            data: {id: data.id, assign: data.target},
            success: function (data) {
            }.bind(this),
            error: function (xhr, status, err) {
                console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
            }.bind(this)
        });
    },
    deleteTask: function (e) {
        var taskIndex = parseInt(e.target.value, 10);
        console.log('remove task: %d', taskIndex);

        $.ajax({
            url: baseUrl + '/api/zlecenia/' + taskIndex,
            type: 'DELETE',
            success: function (data) {
                this.loadConvsFromServer();
            }.bind(this),
            error: function (xhr, status, err) {
                console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
            }.bind(this)
        });

    },
    render: function () {
      return (
       <div className="convlist" onDragOver={this.dragOver}>
            <div className="candrop" id={this.props.id} >{this.props.id}
                {this.state.data.map((c) => 
                    <Conversation  onDrop={this.updatePosition} delay={c.delayTime} id={c.id} key={c.id}>
                        <p className="convTop">{c.formattedTime} | Tel. {c.phone} | {c.name} | Nr.Rej {c.number}</p>
                        <p>{c.text}</p>
                        <button className="deleteConv"  onClick={this.deleteTask} value={c.id}>x</button>
                     </Conversation>
                )}
            </div>
        </div>

      );
    }
});

/**
 * ConvForm
 * Displays conversation create form. Prepares fields, validates them.
 * Call master function to add new record on send.
 */
var ConvForm = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {phone: '', name: '', number: '', text: ''};
    },
    handlePhoneChange: function (e) {
        this.setState({phone: e.target.value});
    },
    handleNameChange: function (e) {
        this.setState({name: e.target.value});
    },
    handleNumberChange: function (e) {
        this.setState({number: e.target.value});
    },
    handleTextChange: function (e) {
        this.setState({text: e.target.value});
    },
    submitForm: function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var phone = this.state.phone.trim();
        var name = this.state.name.trim();
        var number = this.state.number.trim();
        var text = this.state.text.trim();

        if (!text || !phone || !name || !number) {
            return;
        }
        this.props.onConvSubmit({phone: phone, name: name, number: number, text: text});
        this.setState({phone: '', text: '', number: '', name: ''});
    },
    render: function () {
        return (
        <form className="convForm" onSubmit={this.submitForm}>
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <input
                        className="form-control"
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Telefon"
                        value={this.state.phone}
                        onChange={this.handlePhoneChange}
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <input
                        className="form-control"
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Imię i nazwisko"
                        value={this.state.name}
                        onChange={this.handleNameChange}
                      />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <input
                        className="form-control"
                        type="text"
                        placeholder="Nr. rejestracyjny"
                        value={this.state.number}
                        onChange={this.handleNumberChange}
                      />
                    </div>
                 </div>
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
                <textarea
                className="form-control"
                type="text"
                placeholder="Treść"
                value={this.state.text}
                onChange={this.handleTextChange}
                />
            </div>
            <input className="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Zapisz" />
        </form>
                );
    }
});

/**
 * ConvFrame
 * Conversation main frame and root functions for both form and conversations listing.
 */
window.ConvFrame = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {records: []};
    },
    loadCommentsFromServer: function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: baseUrl + '/api/zlecenia',
            type: 'GET',
            data: {id : 1},
            success: function (data) {
                this.setState({records: data});
            }.bind(this),
            error: function (xhr, status, err) {
                console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
            }.bind(this)
        });
    },
    handleCommentSubmit: function (convo) {
        $.ajax({
            url: baseUrl + '/api/zlecenia',
            type: 'POST',
            data: convo,
            success: function (data) {
                this.loadCommentsFromServer();
            }.bind(this),
            error: function (xhr, status, err) {
                console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
            }.bind(this)
        });
    },
  render: function() {
        return (
                <div className="add-new">
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-xs-12 col-md-12 frame">
                                <div className="col-xs-12 col-md-7">
                                    <h3>Dodaj nową rozmowę</h3>
                                    <ConvForm onConvSubmit={this.handleCommentSubmit} />
                                </div>
                                <div className="col-xs-12 col-md-5">
                                    <ConvList key='1' id='1'  data={this.state.records} />
                                </div>  
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
                );
    }
});
```

workers.js

```
/**
 * WorkerList
 * 
 */
var Worker = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
      return (
         <div>
              {this.props.children}
         </div>
      );
    }
});


/**
 * WorkerList
 * 
 */
var WorkerList = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
      return (
       <div className="worker-list">
                {this.props.data.map((worker) => 
                    <Worker id={worker.id} key={worker.id}>
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-xs-12 col-md-12 frame">
                                <div className="col-xs-12 col-md-5">
                                     <h4>{worker.username}</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div className="col-xs-12 col-md-7">
                                <ConvList key={worker.id} id={worker.id} />
                                </div>  
                           </div>
                        </div>
                    </Worker>
                )}

        </div>

      );
    }
});

/**
 * WorkerForm
 * 
 */
var WorkerForm = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
      </div>
    );
  }
});


/**
 * WorkerFame
 * 
 */
window.WorkerFrame = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {data: []};
    },
    loadWorkersFromServer: function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: baseUrl + '/api/pracownicy',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (data) {
                this.setState({data: data});
            }.bind(this),
            error: function (xhr, status, err) {
                console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
            }.bind(this)
        });
    },
    componentDidMount: function () {
        this.loadWorkersFromServer();
    },
    handleWorkerSubmit: function (worker) {
        $.ajax({
            url: baseUrl + '/api/pracownicy',
            type: 'POST',
            data: worker,
            success: function (data) {
                this.loadWorkersFromServer();
            }.bind(this),
            error: function (xhr, status, err) {
                console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
            }.bind(this)
        });
    },
  render: function() {
        return (
                <div className="add-new">
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
                                <WorkerList data={this.state.data} />
                            </div>  
                           <div className="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
                                <WorkerForm onWorkerSubmit={this.handleWorkerSubmit} />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
                );
    }
});
```

final.js

```
var DashFrame = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
      <ConvFrame/>
      <WorkerFrame/>
      </div>
    );
  }
});


ReactDOM.render(
  <DashFrame/>,
  document.getElementById('dashboard')
);
```

Any hints would be appreciated. My brain is boiling.

Comment: Do you have a plunker page for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the (long) code I think your problem arises because your call to server in `<ConvList>` is inside `componentDidMount()`:

```
componentDidMount: function () {
    this.loadConvsFromServer();
},
```

`componentDidMount()` is always only called once, upon initial mount.

So the second time, react does not call `componentDidMount()`, the call to server is not made, your state does not change, and therefore `<ConvList>` is not updated.

To fix, add:

```
componentDidUpdate: function () {
    this.loadConvsFromServer();
},
```

Which is also called when component is updated.

UPDATE: you will also need to add a condition to the resulting `setState()`, otherwise you will get an endless loop (`componentDidUpdate()` -> `setState()` -> `componentDidUpdate()` -> repeat).

Best place is probably inside `loadConvsFromServer()`. Something like:

```
...
success: function (data) {
           var dataChanged = ...
           // some smart comparison of data with this.state.data
           if (dataChanged) {
             this.setState({data: data});
           }
         }.bind(this),
...
```

Also, I noticed this snippet inside `submitForm()` inside `<ConvForm>`:

```
 this.props.onConvSubmit({phone: phone, name: name, number: number, text: text});
 this.setState({phone: '', text: '', number: '', name: ''});
```

This is a dangerous combo: the first call essentially passes control back to the parent, which may (and probably will) re-render the entire tree. And immediately after, you trigger a second render with the `setState()`.  But no way of telling in which order they will be fired.
Cleaner (and easier to debug and maintain) would be to move the `setState()` that clears all inputs to a `componentWillReceiveProps()` lifecycle method. That way, each time your component is re-rendered by its parent, all inputs will clear. Bonus: your component will only re-render once.

Comment: Thanks, but for some reason it does not seem to work. Actually, adding a componentDidUpdate is causing endless loop of server queries, over and over... If you want I can zip the project and mail it to you or upload to some place.

Comment: Yeah, it can cause endless loop. You need to add some condition in `loadConvsFromServer()` to only do `setState()` if stuff changed. Will edit.

Comment: Thank you. You saved me another sleepless night.